# How to build a spark trainingImage for sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-sagemaker

How can I build a trainingImage for a custom spark algorithm as the kmeans trainingImage in amazon-sagemaker-examples/sagemaker-spark/pyspark_mnist/pyspark_mnist_custom_estimator.ipynb ?

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to build your own algorithm for use within the SageMaker PySpark Estimator, you can follow the example for building your own algorithm container here: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/scikit_bring_your_own.ipynb

This example walks through the steps required to build a custom algorithm container that can be used for both training and inference.